# Displaying key name in JSON result inside foreach loop

Tags: php, json

How can I display the key name from a JSON result inside a foreach loop ?

I have tried :

```
$row = $obj->response->result->$module->row;
foreach($row->FL as $data)
  {
   echo key($data);      
  }
```

However this does nothing.

Here is a sample snippet from the JSON result

```
"row": [
          {
            "no": "1",
            "FL": [
              {
                "val": "CONTACTID",
                "content": "3508588000000259007"
              },
```

Its the val I want not the content

```
print_r( $obj->response->result->$module->row);
```

Returns ..

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [no] => 1 [FL] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [val] => ACCOUNTID [content] => 3508588000000259001 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [val] => SMOWNERID [content] => 3508588000000176021 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Account Owner [content] => Chris Yates ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Rating [content] => null ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Account Name [content] => Test Co ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Phone [content] => null ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Account Site [content] => null ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Fax [content] => null ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [val] => PARENTACCOUNTID [content] => null ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Parent Account [content] => null ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Website [content] => null ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Account Number [content] => 0 ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Ticker Symbol [content] => null ) [13] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Account Type [content] => null ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Ownership [content] => null ) [15] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Industry [content] => null ) [16] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Employees [content] => 0 ) [17] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Annual Revenue [content] => 129000 ) [18] => stdClass Object ( [val] => SIC Code [content] => 0 ) [19] => stdClass Object ( [val] => SMCREATORID [content] => 3508588000000176021 ) [20] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Created By [content] => Chris Yates ) [21] => stdClass Object ( [val] => MODIFIEDBY [content] => 3508588000000176021 ) [22] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Modified By [content] => Chris Yates ) [23] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Created Time [content] => 2018-09-20 09:56:30 ) [24] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Modified Time [content] => 2018-09-20 12:39:56 ) [25] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Billing Street [content] => null ) [26] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Shipping Street [content] => null ) [27] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Billing City [content] => null ) [28] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Shipping City [content] => null ) [29] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Billing State [content] => null ) [30] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Shipping State [content] => null ) [31] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Billing Code [content] => null ) [32] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Shipping Code [content] => null ) [33] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Billing Country [content] => null ) [34] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Shipping Country [content] => null ) [35] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Description [content] => null ) [36] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Last Activity Time [content] => 2018-09-20 12:39:56 ) [37] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Tag [content] => null ) ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [no] => 2 [FL] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [val] => ACCOUNTID [content] => 3508588000000180068 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [val] => SMOWNERID [content] => 3508588000000176021 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Account Owner [content] => Chris Yates ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Rating [content] => null ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Account Name [content] => Google Inc ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Phone [content] => null ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Account Site [content] => null ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Fax [content] => null ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [val] => PARENTACCOUNTID [content] => null ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Parent Account [content] => null ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Website [content] => null ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Account Number [content] => 0 ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Ticker Symbol [content] => null ) [13] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Account Type [content] => null ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Ownership [content] => null ) [15] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Industry [content] => null ) [16] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Employees [content] => 0 ) [17] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Annual Revenue [content] => 0 ) [18] => stdClass Object ( [val] => SIC Code [content] => 0 ) [19] => stdClass Object ( [val] => SMCREATORID [content] => 3508588000000176021 ) [20] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Created By [content] => Chris Yates ) [21] => stdClass Object ( [val] => MODIFIEDBY [content] => 3508588000000176021 ) [22] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Modified By [content] => Chris Yates ) [23] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Created Time [content] => 2018-09-07 11:24:26 ) [24] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Modified Time [content] => 2018-09-10 12:52:43 ) [25] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Billing Street [content] => null ) [26] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Shipping Street [content] => null ) [27] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Billing City [content] => null ) [28] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Shipping City [content] => null ) [29] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Billing State [content] => null ) [30] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Shipping State [content] => null ) [31] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Billing Code [content] => null ) [32] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Shipping Code [content] => null ) [33] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Billing Country [content] => null ) [34] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Shipping Country [content] => null ) [35] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Description [content] => null ) [36] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Last Activity Time [content] => 2018-09-26 13:34:14 ) [37] => stdClass Object ( [val] => Tag [content] => null ) ) ) )
```

Comment: Try to print out `foreach($row as $data)` instead

Comment: $row is an array, and doesn't have an "FL" property

Comment: See this is whats confusing me
If I print $row = $obj->response->result->$module->row->FL->content;
I get the content data however if i change it to val I get nothing

Comment: All I get is an error relating to a count function further down the page for the row count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can clearly be seen by looking at the original JSON, `$row` is an array, and doesn't have an `FL` property. You could also do a `var_dump($row)` in PHP to see the structure.

`FL` will be a property of the first item in the array. e.g. `$row[0]->FL`; Then `FL` itself is also an array. Therefore `$row[0]->FL[0]->val` should output what you need.

Live demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ead7c866d5c09d24c7b9585f4e6d5ddebc184186

Based on the sample JSON provided, this will output `CONTACTID`.

If you have multiple items in FL, and want to output them all, you can use a loop. Here's a very simple example to produce a comma-separated list:

```
foreach ($row[0]->FL as $fl)
  echo $fl->val.", ";
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/65efcac539bccb806f0264ba783ae7b005f892b8

Comment: Yep can see your example working but for some strange reason I'm not getting that

Comment: @ChrisYates well in the print_r example you've provided, the val of the first item is ACCOUNTID - it appears to be a different dataset from the one you showed in the JSON. But the structure is the same.

Comment: Also I dont want it displaying just the val on the first FL i need it to display all val inside FL

Comment: well it was hard to tell that from a sample of 1...but you just need a foreach loop

Comment: I did say a snippet of the result and it was in a foreach loop ;)

Comment: $json = file_get_contents($url);
 $obj = json_decode($json);
 $row = $obj->response->result->$module->row[0]->FL;

  foreach($row as $data)
  {
echo $row->val;
}
Thats what I've tried but nothing

Unless I set FL[0] which only picks up the 1st val it doesnt work its way through each

Comment: I've edited it to show a simple example of looping to list them all. In your example in the comment above you'd need to `echo $data->val` by the way. $row is the list, $data is the individual object within it. Check the [PHP docs for foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) if you're unsure what each variable represents in the syntax.

Comment: Ahh .. the the row[0]->FL in the foreach fixed it ..

Many thanks :)

Comment: I think actually it was the difference between which variable is used in the `echo` which fixed it. Look at [this demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e964999e79b49c7d3e32dc4d06c05af299ab32c8) - you can use $row in the foreach _statement_ with no problem (I've made it so it's just an alias for the FL array the same as you did), but using $row _within_ the loop makes no sense.